# JetPack Compose - remove extra padding from view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a few Icons in a `row`

```
    Row {
    IconButton {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.im1)
        )
    },
    IconButton {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.im2)
        )
    }
}
```

But when it's displayed the distance between 2 icons in the `row` is bigger then I expect. I feel like there is 32dp spacer between them. How can I decrease the distance between 2 icons inside a `row`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The space between the 2 icons it is not a padding and depends by the default size of the `IconButton`.
It is due to accessibility touch targets and allows the correct minimum touch target size.
You can change it disabling the `LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement` and applying a `Modifier.size(24.dp)` to the `IconButton`:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false){
    Row {
        IconButton(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
            onClick = {}) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_add_24px),""
            )
        }
        IconButton(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
            onClick = {}) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_add_24px),""
            )
        }
    }
}
```

As alternative you can use an `Icon` with the `Modifier.clickable`:

```
Row {
    Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_add_24px),"",
        modifier = Modifier.clickable (onClick = {} )
        )
    Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_add_24px),"",
        modifier = Modifier.clickable (onClick = {} )
        )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Modifier.then(Modifier.size(24.dp) worked. thanks!

Comment: @Rainmaker `Modifier.then(Modifier.size(24.dp))` has no sense at all. It's totally equivalent of `Modifier.size(24.dp)`, try it out

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to control the exact distance, it is viable to implement a `Layout`, giving you complete control over the offset (yes you could also just use the offset Modifier, but I find this more promising.

```
Layout(
 content = {
  IconButton {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.im1)
        )
    },
    IconButton {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.im2)
        )
    }
 }
){ measurables, constraints ->
 val icon1 = measurables[0].measure(constraints)
 val icon2 = measurables[1].measure(constraints)
 
 layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight){ //Change these to suit your requirements
 //Use place(x, y) to specify exact co-ordinates within the container
 icon1.place(0, 0)
 icon2.place(icon1.width, 0) //Places Directly where icon1 ends

/*If padding still appears, you can subtract some function from the second icon's starting point to make it even closer than the edge of iicon1
*/
}
```

This should be it!