# How can I place an icon on the right of screen without padding in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I run Code A and get Image A.

You can find the text *"World"* on the right of screen without padding, and the icon *Edit* on the right of screen with some padding.

How can I make the icon *Edit* on the right of screen without padding ?

**Code A**

```
   Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ){
        Text("Hello",Modifier.weight(1f))
        Text("World")
    }


    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ){
        Text("Hello",Modifier.weight(1f))

        IconButton(
            enabled = true,
            onClick = {
            }
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Edit, null, modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp))
        }

    }
```

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134937/jetpack-compose-remove-extra-padding-from-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Clicked]

When you click you could see that there is a ripple effect.
The padding is added by the `IconButton`. By default, `Icon` does not have this padding.

Before making a decision on the solution, there are a few things we have to consider.

1. Does the icon have a click action? (Is it intended to be used as an `Icon` or as an `IconButton`)
2. If it has a click action, do you need the default ripple effect provided by Material design `IconButton`?

For all the cases mentioned below, the first step is to Remove the `IconButton` wrapping the `Icon`.

**1** If the icon does not have a click action.
You already have what you want once you remove the `IconButton`.

**2** If the icon has a click action, but you do not require the ripple effect.
Add a `clickable` modifier on the `Icon` to handle the click action.

**3** If the icon has a click action and you do require the ripple effect.
Add a `clickable` modifier on the `Icon` to handle the click action as well as an indication for the ripple effect.

**Sample**

```
Icon(
    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Edit, 
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(20.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .clickable(
            onClick = {},
        )
        .indication(
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
            indication = rememberRipple(),
        ),
)
```

There is also a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69135117/9636037) to change `size`. If you want to have the same size ripple effect as it is currently, that would help.

I have manually added the ripple to `Icon` so that the ripple is only as big as the icon.

---

**Additional info**

#### Why and how is there padding in the IconButton?

If we go through the `IconButton` source code, we can find `Modifier.minimumTouchTargetSize()`.

`minimumTouchTargetSize()`

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Suppress("ModifierInspectorInfo")
internal fun Modifier.minimumTouchTargetSize(): Modifier = composed(
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        name = "minimumTouchTargetSize"
        // TODO: b/214589635 - surface this information through the layout inspector in a better way
        //  - for now just add some information to help developers debug what this size represents.
        properties["README"] = "Adds outer padding to measure at least 48.dp (default) in " +
            "size to disambiguate touch interactions if the element would measure smaller"
    }
) {
    if (LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement.current) {
        // TODO: consider using a hardcoded value of 48.dp instead to avoid inconsistent UI if the
        // LocalViewConfiguration changes across devices / during runtime.
        val size = LocalViewConfiguration.current.minimumTouchTargetSize
        MinimumTouchTargetModifier(size)
    } else {
        Modifier
    }
}
```

Material design guidelines recommends a minimum of `48.dp` size for touch targets so that they are easily accessible.

Also, a point to think about if you are considering reducing touch target size.